# How to calculate mutual information?

Tags: python, information-theory, mutual-information, numpy, pandas

I am a bit confused. Can someone explain to me how to calculate mutual information between two terms based on a term-document matrix with binary term occurrence as weights?

$$
\begin{matrix}
          & 'Why' & 'How' & 'When' & 'Where' \\ 
Document1 &   1   &   1   &   1    &    1    \\ 
Document2 &   1   &   0   &   1    &    0    \\ 
Document3 &   1   &   1   &   1    &    0
\end{matrix}
$$

$$I(X;Y)= \sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x \in X} p(x,y) \log\left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)} \right)$$

Thank you

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: X and Y are terms. X could be "Why" and Y could be "How".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about forming a joint probability table holding the normalized co-occurences in documents. Then you can obtain joint entropy and marginal entropies using the table. Finally, 
$$I(X,Y) = H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y). $$

Comment: When the joint and marginal distributions have been determined, why is it necessary to compute $H(X)$, $H(Y)$ and $H(X,Y)$ and use the formula you exhibit? Can't the mutual information be determined directly via the formula given by the OP since everything needed for "plugging in", viz. $p(x,y), p(x)$ and $p(y)$ are known at this point?

Comment: formulas are equivalent except the latter can be more interpretable at first glance.